# Can't check if array is nil, what are the alternatives?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8

I am getting an object with parse.com, which is actually a String array. Then I try to check if its nil or not. The compiler doesn't let me do this. When I try to put the value into another object I get a crash. How to fix this?

```
object["Comments"] //this is the object, it is AnyObject atm, but it actually is an array of strings
```

The code:

```
findFeedData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

if (error == nil){
  for object in objects{

    var commentObject = [String]()

    if object["Comments"] == nil {
      //It never gets to this part.. Even though it is nil and I get crash
      println(object["Comments"])
      commentObject = object["Comments"] as [String]
    }else{
      //I get this even if its nil or not
      println(object["Comments"])
      commentObject = object["Comments"] as [String]  //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    } 

  }        
  var row: FeedData = FeedData(comm:commentObject)
}
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `object`? Is it an optional, and/or contains optional types?

Comment: objects:[AnyObject]!

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code... `objects["Comments"]` indicates that `object` is a dictionary, but you say it's an array. How is that possible?

Comment: that object is part of a dictionary, but inside that there is an array.

Comment: Here are some of the values of object["Comments"] when printed:
nil
nil
Optional((
    hey,
    dude,
    man
))

Comment: What about `if let commentObject = object["Comments"] { ... `?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
if let commentObject = object["Comments"] as? [String]{
  dude = commentObject
}else{
  dude = [String]()
}
```

Comment: See the docs [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C - Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

Comment: Yeah, I did. Wasn't really helpful, I kinda found the fix randomly while trying different things. Looks like a language bug

Comment: really a condition of bridging Obj-c to Swift.

Comment: You can just inline the assignment and conditional with `if let commentObject = object["Comments"] as? [String] { ...`

Comment: Also, if you are not making changes to the commentObject, you may want to use `let` instead of `var`.